# Django Storages [file upload to AWS S3]

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3, python-django-storages

I am using django storages library for upload my files to s3. I want to understand how this file uploads works , does the file uploads to s3 folder directly or it uploads to my server and then goes to s3?

How does the file upload works in django storages.

If I upload multiple files , will they use bandwidth of my server of will they be directly uploaded to s3 and will not slow the speed of my server.

Thank you

Comment: I have found a package which is handling it. 
https://github.com/dabapps/django-s3-file-upload-server

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to leave comments like this but ... **excellent question**. I found this question wondering if Django Storages uploads directly to S3 or not.

Answer (score 4):

Django-storage uses `boto3` for uploads, as can be seen in its source code [here](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/770332b598712da27ecdba75c9e202ad6a1a8722/storages/backends/s3boto3.py):

```
obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=params)
```

which is the [upload_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj) method in `boto3`:

> Upload a **file-like object** to this bucket. The file-like object must be in binary mode. This is a managed transfer which will perform a **multipart** upload in multiple threads if necessary.

Looking at the [save](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L38) method in `Django-storage` it future explains:

> Save new content to the file specified by name. The content should be  a proper File object or any Python **file-like object**, ready to be read from the beginning.

So to answer your question, the file must go through your server first so that you can create `file-like object` for it. It does not have to be necessarily stored on a hard drive, but the file data can be in memory. Also I think it also does not have to be fully stored, it should be possible to steam it as its being uploaded to your app, but I'm not certain if this works in django.

To sum up, all uploaded files must go through your server taking it processing power and bandwidth.

Comment: I am uploading files from mobile so what is the best approach for file uploading to s3? should I use pre signed URL or write lambda function to handle file uploads separately. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AqeelRaza Depends on the nature and your use-case. If you just want to upload files as they are, presigned url would allow you to upload directly to S3. If you want to do some pre-processing or verification of files before they end up in S3, then you could do this using lambda.